# Is there any proper way to make a request when component mount or change on every component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I would like to call an api request

- when component mount
- when jumping screen to screen

Here is that api sample code

```
{
   "api_update_list": {
      "menu": "2021-04-10 04:00:24",
      "posts": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "category": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "products": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "wishlist": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "collection": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "hot_items": "2021-04-10 04:00:34",
      "people": "2021-04-10 04:00:34"
   }
}
```

The reason why I would like to call that api because I would like to check offline data is update or not. I save all my data with react-persist. Let's say I have 4 component. ( In reality, I might have many components)

```
const ScreenA = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const appStatus = useSelector(state => state.app.status); //it is from redux with default value idle

    useEffect(() => {
        if ( appStatus === "idle" && isConnected ) {
            dispatch(fetchAppData()); //Data by createAsyncThunk
        }
    }, [appStatus])

    return(
        <Text>Screen A</Text>
    )
}
```

```
const ScreenB = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const appStatus = useSelector(state => state.app.status); //it is from redux with default value idle

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(statusUpdate('idle')); //I have to reset idle in every component like that to request again
    }, [appStatus])

    return(
        <Text>Screen B</Text>
    )
}
```

```
const ScreenC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const appStatus = useSelector(state => state.app.status); //it is from redux with default value idle

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(statusUpdate('idle')); //I have to reset idle in every component like that to request again
    }, [appStatus])

    return(
        <Text>Screen C</Text>
    )
}
```

**Note**

- I don't want to request data again if I save that data in AsyncStorage.
- I would decide data should be requested or not by checking date andtime from data api(api format sample code is above).

**Please let me know your experienced like this situation.**

Comment: Have you looked into useFocusEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correctly you want to do your validations on every route change.
My suggestion is to use a high level listener so you don't need to repeat your code on every screen component.

I'll assume you are using the `react-navigation` lib for your routes, in this case you could do something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      onStateChange={(state) => {
        // here you can call your validations and update your data
        // it will be called everytime the navigation state changes even on tabs switch
      }}
      initialState={initialState}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I'm showing this example with the most used navigation lib but most of them have an equivalent function.

For more information on this callback:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#onstatechange